# How to convert decimal short output?

Tags: linux

With `od  -N 64 -i mpich`
on Ubuntu 14.04 I have

```
0000000  1135000353  1135000810  1135005924  1135016843
0000020  1135027542  1135036186  1135041461  1135041331
0000040  1135043045  1135052773  1135063618  1135067789
0000060  1135064934  1135052521  1135033974  1135019865
0000100
```

How to convert these decimal shorts into ascii?

Comment: `od -c` shows characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show "these" decimals:

```
perl -ane 'shift @F; print map {pack "l",$_ } @F' <<EOS | od -c
0000000  1135000353  1135000810  1135005924  1135016843
0000020  1135027542  1135036186  1135041461  1135041331
0000040  1135043045  1135052773  1135063618  1135067789
0000060  1135064934  1135052521  1135033974  1135019865
0000100
EOS
```